# How to update multiple duplicates of the same image in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I have multiple of the same image placed in different spots, but I'd like to be able to switch a single image and have it applied on all other instances of the image.

Here is the image I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: Not trying to edit effects, I'm trying to change the base image

Comment: You should have made the image smart objects before you made them

Comment: They are smart objects

Comment: If they're smart objects then double click one to edit it and replace your image? What is it you're having a trouble with?

Comment: What part of it is a smart object and what are you trying to update? Can you [edit] your question to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different ways to copy a Smart Object:

- **Duplicate**. The copy is a *reference* to the original Smart Object. If you edit either one of the copies all instances will update.
- **New Smart Object via Copy**. The copy is a *new* Smart Object with no connection to the original. The copies can be edited separately without affecting each other.

If you have made your copies with the first method you can simply edit one of the Smart Objects and all the other instances should update accordingly. If you have used the second method, I'm afraid you'll have to recreate your design using the first method.